# How to use Intersect with a Table Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm needing to modify my code below to use a table range rather than a cell range. The code below allows the selected cells between the given range to change from 9 to 0 and back again if selected. However I need this to work with a Table so for example Table1 Column1 is my range rather than G5 to G1604. I would like it so that when I specify Column1 for it to get the whole of that column as the range

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G5:G1604")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target.Value = 9 Then
        Target.Value = 0
    Else
    Target.Value = 9
  End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this great tutorial on [Excel VBA for Tables](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

Your code will look like this (adjust Table name and column reference accordingly):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Not Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange)) Is Nothing Then
  If Target.Value = 9 Then 
        Target.Value = 0
    Else
    Target.Value = 9
  End If
 End If

End Sub
```

*As a side note:* Are you sure you want this code to fire **everytime** you move from one cell to another on the worksheet? Or do you want it to fire everytime you make a change to a cell in the column of the table? If the latter, change to `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Many thank, no its on a selection I need it to work for my application, but i'm new to working with tables still trying to get my head around them so cheers for the tutorial